# Why is my javascript function not returning true?

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript function :

```
function isInSupplier(idsupplier) {
    suppliers.forEach(function(object) {
        if (object._id == idsupplier) {
            console.log("TRUE");
            return true;
        };
    });
    return false;
```

I have a list of products, each have a suppliers. I want to make a list of unique suppliers, therefore is the supplier is already in my suppliers list i will not add a new one.

Here is my function to do so :

```
    console.log(isInSupplier(('<s:property value="supplier.id" />')));
    if (!isInSupplier(('<s:property value="supplier.id" />'))) {
        suppliers.push(new supplier(
                ('<s:property value="supplier.id" />'),
                ('<s:property value="supplier.supplier_name" />'),
                ('<s:property value="supplier.type" />'),
                ('<s:property value="supplier.phone" />')
        ));
    }
```

And there is something i don't understand : even tho the console logs "TRUE" properly, the function doesn't return true. In my second block of code i have another console log; that always logs false.

What is it i'm missing ?

Comment: You return only from your closure. I.e forEach. Your external function only returns false and thats what you are seeing

Comment: You are returning true only inside the forEach() function. The function you are wondering about always returns false

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please change it to [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

> The `some()` method tests whether some element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function.

```
function isInSupplier(idsupplier) {
    return suppliers.some(function(object) {
        if (object._id == idsupplier) {
            console.log("TRUE");
            return true;
        };
    });
}
```

or without console output

```
function isInSupplier(idsupplier) {
    return suppliers.some(function(object) {
        return object._id == idsupplier;
    });
}
```

Comment: Ah yes `some` was what I was looking for, but I can never remember the JS higher-order function names.

Answer (score 2):

`forEach` method takes function as a parameter. If you return inside it you wont return from outer function. You can use `Array.prototype.some` to make it work:

```
function isInSupplier(idsupplier) {
    return suppliers.some(function (object) {
        return object._id == idsupplier;
    });
}
```

If your environment supports ES6 you can utilize it with arrow function:

```
function isInSupplier(idsupplier) {
    return suppliers.some(o => o._id == idsupplier);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are returning true from the function you pass to `forEach`, not from `isInSupplier`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `return true` returns the function passed to `forEach`, not `isInSupplier`. Instead you can use [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex):

```
function isInSupplier(idsupplier) {
  var index = suppliers.findIndex(function(object) {
    return object._id == idsupplier;
  });
  return index != -1
}
```

Or really probably better to use [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) as in Nina’s answer (I couldn’t remember the name so resorted to `findIndex`).